# Emergency mode after update Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, filesystem, 17.04

Ubuntu 17.04 does not start normally after update. I try several runlevels.

I can't go to runlevel 5 and 3 as graphic mode. lightdm never starts!

[image: the image after boot]

errors in `dmesg` after boot:

```
    [    0.144583] ACPI Error: [_PPC] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160930/dswload-378)
[    0.160586] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[   12.455982] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   13.807652] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.813076] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.813094] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.832814] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
```

errors in `journalctl -xb` result:

```
مه 20 09:42:32 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: ACPI Error: [_PPC] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160930/dswload-378)
مه 20 09:42:32 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
مه 20 09:42:35 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
مه 20 09:42:35 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
مه 20 09:42:35 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
مه 20 09:42:35 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
مه 20 09:42:41 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK systemd-fsck[691]: home contains a file system with errors, check forced.
مه 20 09:42:43 hamid-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK systemd-fsck[691]: fsck failed with error code 4.
```

What I'm asking is, how can I exit emergency mode, and fix the OS to usability?

Comment: I don't see where you tried to change runlevels... you just apparently have a corrupt home fs and the fsck failed, so you are in emergency mode.

Comment: With systemd the runlevel metaphor has been replaced by "targets". But your question is very unclear to me.

Comment: thank you Zanna for correction. actually my /home partition has  needed fsck. I edited fstab and split /home partition with a # comment sign. then when I reboot system all things go back good. so I run fsck on /home drive. almost ask a question is the half of answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Welcome to emergency mode!” Think it is a fsck problem](/q/646414/175814)